# Allow rendering variants/styles based on selected Theme SXA

Tags: sxa

I'm curious if it's possible or someone tried to implement something like: Allow rendering variants/styles based on selected Theme.

There is already an `Allow in Template` filter on rendering variants in SXA but nothing like to filter by the theme. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we needed to write up a custom processor to filter out the styles for a specific SXA Theme.

Comment: Have you got an example?